# Dropdown list's awkward behaviour when in small screen/different orientation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, razor

I'm working on some old code and I've come across a problem which is a bit puzzling. I have a dropdown list with about 5 items in it. If there is area for the list to open properly all is well (Opens as popup over existing content). But when there isn't (due to screensize/orientation), I get the list showing but with a black background. Is there some way to force the list to open as if there was space as in the first option?

```
<div  style="font-size: smaller">
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedContext, new SelectList(Model.Contexts, "ContextID", "Label")
    , new { id = "select-choice-1", @class = "contextmenu", data_theme="c" , name = "select-choice-1", data_native_menu="false" })
</div>
```

using jquery 1.8.3 and mobile 1.3.2

**EDIT**: When the problematic condition occurs, I can see below elements magically appearing.

```
<div data-role="dialog" id="select-choice-1-dialog" data-theme="c" data-overlay-theme="a" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-dialog ui-overlay-a ui-page-active" data-url="select-choice-1-dialog" style="min-height: 190px;">
<div role="dialog" class="ui-dialog-contain ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MartinOnTheNet for his great direction.

The problem was due to .live() function on the scripts using this div creating confusion for some reason. Changed all .live() on the page to .on() function. Something like below;

```
$(#pageDiv).live('pagecreate', function (event) {
    $(".contextmenu").change(function () {
    ...
```

to;

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#pageDiv', function (event) {
    $(".contextmenu").change(function () {
    ...
```

Also used **allowSamePageTransition: true** as below. $.mobile.navigate also works but then I lost the back functionality.

```
$.mobile.changePage("../Controller/Action?ItemID=" + $("#select-choice-1").attr("value"),
{
   allowSamePageTransition: true
});
```

What didnt work;

- forcing orientation.
- forcing screen size larger than the dropdown
- list size fiddling with overlay attributes adding events to the
- anything to overlay with live or bind (`.live("ready"...`,...)
- `$(#pageDiv).die()` killed all bound events
- And some more forgotten weird coding experiments

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood your question...

Unfortunately for you, this behaviour is built-in jquery mobile framework. When the number of items is greater than the size of the screen, it opens a new page, which is used to display all items.

You can read about this [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html)!

Extracted from doc (link above)

> *When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a
>   standard listview for the options. This allows us to use the native
>   scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list. The
>   text inside the label is used as the title for this page.*

In my case, I avoid using custom dropdowns, and use the native from device. If you want to set the native one, simply change data-native-menu='true'

```
data_native_menu="true"
```

Hope helps,

Comment: This is exactly the situation. The reason I'm looking for a way around is when the new list '**page**' comes up it doesnt actually work. Like trigger any js and etc.

Comment: Ok, also remember if you are handling any events in the main page, such 'pagechange', or 'pageshow' make sure that they are link to the div page ID. Otherwise the dropdown when opens means you are changing to a new page and showing it.